# Alternate way to get Azure AD sign in logs in Python without using subprocess library and powershell.exe

Tags: python, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-automation

As far as I can tell by looking at other posts, using the subprocess library in Python is the most popular way to execute PowerShell commands from within Python. For example:

```
data = subprocess.check_output(["powershell.exe", "Connect-AzureAD -AccountId me@me.com \n Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs"]).decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
```

However, I'm ultimately trying to add this script to an automation account in Azure. Specifying the executable "powershell.exe" in the script won't work in an Azure automation account runbook (raises a "FileNotFound" error).

Is there some other way you can get the sign in log data from within Python that would be more amenable to using in an Azure automation account runbook? Can the Azure library be used to get sign in log data instead?

Comment: All this data is exposed by the Microsoft Graph REST API. These Powershell commands actually call these APIs. Wrapping a Powershell session in pyhton around this is in my opinion a bad design choise since you can call these API's using any webclient in any language and framework

Comment: Makes sense, I couldn't find how to call the API using a webclient in Python specifically for sign in logs, is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested in my environment

You can use MS Graph API query in your python script to get the Azure AD sign in logs of the users

You can use below python code:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns'
token = "access_token"

headers = {
 'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token)
}

user_response_data = json.loads(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text)
print(user_response_data)
```

**Reference**: [Querying Microsoft Graph API with Python | by Ephraim Mwai | Towards Data Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/querying-microsoft-graph-api-with-python-269118e8180c)